# Why won't knockout update the value in my textbox?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

*(This is an extremely simplified example of a problem I ran into. It might not make too much functional sense)*

I need a textbox that I can type currency into, that will translate to an int on the viewmodel and to a nicely formatted value in the textbox

I took the code from

[Example 4: Filtering and validating user input](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-writable.html)

And threw away lastInputWasValid and the NaN-test.

My result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cvv341ro/8

If I type 1234, the value of `acceptedNumericValue` will be 1234 and the value in the textbox will be €1234. Good!

If I type €567.0,  the value of `acceptedNumericValue` will be 567 and the value in the textbox will be €567. Brilliant!

But, If I *then* type 567.0000 (the same as the accepted value), knockout will write a value to `acceptedNumericValue` that's already there, and not update the textbox.

I get this :) so I'll give knockout a kick, and call `valueHasMutated` on the `acceptedNumericValue` to make it work

I can see the computed being called, but the textbox will not change the text to €567, whatever I do.

Why!? :'(

Very short recap: run the jsfiddle -> change the text to 123.0 -> blur -> why won't the textbox update to €123?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design and you have to use the `notify` extender on your computed, to trigger the recalculation even if the value is not changing (123.0  == 123):

```
this.attemptedValue = ko.pureComputed({
    read: function() {
        return "€" + this.acceptedNumericValue();
    },
    write: function (value) {
        value = parseInt(value.replace("€", ""));
        this.acceptedNumericValue(value);
        this.acceptedNumericValue.valueHasMutated();
    },
    owner: this
}).extend({notify: 'always'});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2s3ntey/).

From the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#forcing-computed-observables-to-always-notify-subscribers):

> When a computed observable returns a primitive value (a number, string, boolean, or null), the dependencies of the observable are normally only notified if the value actually changed. However, it is possible to use the built-in `notify` extender to ensure that a computed observable’s subscribers are always notified on an update, even if the value is the same.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, I do now vaguely remember this, but I could have never figured it out on my own. Thank you!